# Focusing on a tabified QDockWidget in PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have three QDockWidgets which are tabbed at startup using `QMainWindow.tabifyDockWidget`.

In the main window, after all of the `addDockWidget` calls:

```
self.tabifyDockWidget(self.dock_widget1, self.dock_widget2)
self.tabifyDockWidget(self.dock_widget1, self.dock_widget3)
```

Based on certain actions, I'd like to select one of these tabs and bring it to focus, or, on top of the other two, if it's not already visible.  I've tried using `setVisible` and `setWindowState(Qt.WindowActive)`, but nothing changes.

Is there a way to programmatically select a tabbed dock widget and bring it to the front?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to an answer on the qt-interest mailing list, this is very simple to do with `QWidget.raise()`:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#raise

In PyQt, it's `QWidget.raise_()`:

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#raise

Answer (score 9):

For me:

dock2.show();

dock2.raise();

was enough. But yes, both are needed!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but here's what I would try in Qt 4.5+ (I'll leave the PyQt conversion to you):

```
class MyMainWindow ; // A QMainWindow

void MyMainWindow::bringToFront( QDockWidget* dockIn )
{
   QList<QDockWidget*> docks = tabifiedDockWidgets( dockIn ) ;
   foreach( QDockWidget* dock, docks )
   {
      // Move second dock on top of first dock widget.
      tabifyDockWidget( dock, dockIn ) ;
   }
}
```

See [`QMainWindow::tabifiedDockWidgets()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#tabifiedDockWidgets) and [`QMainWindow::tabifyDockWidget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#tabifyDockWidget).

Comment: This definitely works, the only issue is that it reorders the tabs which is non-ideal.  So far, it seems like this is only solution...thanks for the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is working for me is :

```
tabifyDockWidget(dock1, dock2)
dock2.setVisible(True)
dock2.setFocus()
dock2.raise_()
```

That 3 functions seem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me:

```
dock2.raise_()
```

I managed to get it working using:

```
dock2.show()
parent.tabifyDockWidget(dock1, dock2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution to set the focus to the widget and not leave it on a tabified QDockWidget in the background you can use the [visibility-changed signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#visibilityChanged) and a [focus proxy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocusProxy) like this:

```
class Dock(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.visibilityChanged.connect(self.setVisibility)

    def setVisibility(self, visible):
        if visible: self.setFocus()

    def setWidget(self, widget:QWidget):
        super().setWidget(widget)
        self.setFocusProxy(widget)
```

a little working example:

```
app = QApplication([])
main = QMainWindow()
dock1 = Dock('Dock1', main )
dock1.setWidget(QTextEdit(dock1))
dock2 = Dock('Dock2', main )
dock2.setWidget(QTextEdit(dock2))
main.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, dock1)
main.tabifyDockWidget(dock1, dock2)
main.show()
app.exec()
```